# How to install a Mantis dvb-s card?

Tags: dvb

I am a newbie to ubuntu and  I am trying to fix this along time ago now.
I am running **14.4 lts** distro.

I tried to install all kinds of software that plays dvb card **Azure wave Mantis**
but it keep saying i don't have one.

after executing the command `sudo lshw` I got this output :

```
...
        *-pci:2
             description: PCI bridge
             product: 82801 PCI Bridge
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1e
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1e.0
             version: e1
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci subtractive_decode bus_master cap_list
             resources: ioport:fdd00000(size=1048576)
           *-multimedia UNCLAIMED
                description: Multimedia controller
                product: Mantis DTV PCI Bridge Controller [Ver 1.0]
                vendor: Twinhan Technology Co. Ltd
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
                version: 01
                width: 32 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: bus_master
                configuration: latency=32 maxlatency=255 mingnt=8
                resources: memory:fddff000-fddfffff
```

so please anyone tell me what to do to install the **dvb-s** card and use it?

Comment: to find a driver for your card, consult [linuxtv.org](http://www.linuxtv.org/wiki/index.php/DVB-S_PCI_Cards), it is the reference for TV on LINUX

Comment: Instead of creating several questions, I suggest you to merge all information in one question by **Editing** your question. The more you edit your question, the more it will be visible.

Answer (score 1):

Having a look on LinuxTV site, I've found that:
<sub>***Note*** that I do not have a DVB-S card and that I ve not tested these 2 solutions below</sub>

### For a DVB-S PCI Cards

From this source on [linuxtv.org about **DVB-S PCI Cards**](http://www.linuxtv.org/wiki/index.php/DVB-S_PCI_Cards)

> A linux driver which can be downloaded for the Mantis family from the Twinhan website ([AZLinux_v1.4.2_CI_FC6](http://www.twinhan.com/files/AW/Linux/AZLinux_v1.4.2_CI_FC6.tar.gz)). The mantis_vp1034 only has precompiled module binaries that are only suitable for the first FC6 kernel.
>   
>   Other drivers are available from http://jusst.de/manu/mantis-v4l-dvb.tar.bz2
>   
>   v4l-dvb v5 (s2api) drivers are avaliable from the mercurial repository at http://mercurial.intuxication.org/hg/s2-liplianin

---

### For a **Azurewave AD SP400 CI**

(*reading all your different questions, I suppose it is the card you have*):

From this source on [linuxtv.org about **this card**](http://www.linuxtv.org/wiki/index.php/Azurewave_AD_SP400_CI_%28VP-1041%29),
- No firmware required.
- Follow this to install the Driver:

```
sudo apt-get install mercurial
hg clone http://linuxtv.org/hg/v4l-dvb
```

then

```
cd v4l-dvb/v4l
make
sudo make install
sudo reboot
```

if compiling fails because of FiredTV just run:

```
sudo make menuconfig
```

before the `make` command and disable -> Multimedia Support -> DVB/ATSC Adapter -> Firedtv/Floppydtv

---

Alternatively, try this driver:

```
sudo apt-get install mercurial
hg clone http://jusst.de/hg/mantis-v4l
ln -s mantis-v4l s2   [the scan-s2 and szap-s2 Makefiles expect this]
cd mantis-v4l
make
sudo make install
sudo reboot
```

Comment: i tried the first method when i made my make command this output came 
Updating/Creating .config
Preparing to compile for kernel version 3.3.0
File not found: /lib/modules/3.3.0-32-generic/build/.config at ./scripts/make_kconfig.pl line 32, <IN> line 4.
make: *** No rule to make target `.myconfig', needed by `config-compat.h'.  Stop.

Comment: when i tryed to make sudo make install this came 
-e 
Removing obsolete files from /lib/modules/3.3.0-32-generic/kernel/drivers/media/dvb/frontends:

-e 
Removing obsolete files from /lib/modules/3.3.0-32-generic/kernel/drivers/media/common:

-e 
Removing obsolete files from /lib/modules/3.3.0-32-generic/kernel/drivers/media/video:

-e 
Removing obsolete files from /lib/modules/3.3.0-32-generic/kernel/drivers/media/dvb/cinergyT2:

Comment: Installing kernel modules under /lib/modules/3.3.0-32-generic/kernel/drivers/media/:
/sbin/depmod -a 3.3.0-32-generic 
depmod: ERROR: could not open directory /lib/modules/3.3.0-32-generic: No such file or directory
depmod: FATAL: could not search modules: No such file or directory
make: *** [media-install] Error 1

Comment: hg clone http://jusst.de/hg/mantis-v4l 
doesn't work

Comment: @AmrZenga can you confirm that your card is a **Azurewave AD SP400 CI** ? Page from [LinuxTv](http://www.linuxtv.org/wiki/index.php/Azurewave_AD_SP400_CI_%28VP-1041%29) is from 2010, might be too old to work now. I ll check if I found something more recent ...

Comment: @AmrZenga I edited the beginning of my answer with a new solution

Answer (score 0):

Unclaimed means there isn't a driver attached for that module and it will not work until one is installed.

I don't have that specific hardware, however, some useful results turned up here:
http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1539309.html

Comment: when i get to the make step i got this error "No version yet, using 3.13.0-34-generic
scripts/make_makefile.pl
Updating/Creating .config
Preparing to compile for kernel version 3.3.0
File not found: /lib/modules/3.3.0-34-generic/build/.config at ./scripts/make_kconfig.pl line 32, <IN> line 4.
Updating/Creating .config
Preparing to compile for kernel version 3.3.0
File not found: /lib/modules/3.3.0-34-generic/build/.config at ./scripts/make_kconfig.pl line 32, <IN> line 4.
make: *** No rule to make target `.myconfig', needed by `config-compat.h'.  Stop.
"